# Help with proving a logical equivalence

Tags: logic

How do I prove this using logical equivalences?

$(p \rightarrow q) \lor (q \land r) \equiv \neg ((p \land \neg r) \land \neg q) \land \neg (r \land (\neg q \land p))$

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
Stuff I've tried so far:

Using the law of implication to change the $p \rightarrow q$ into $\neg p \lor q$

It seems like $r$ appears on both sides of the $\land$ in the final expression, so I tried expanding the single $r$ in $q \land r$ into $r \land r$ to give $q \land (r \land r)$ but that doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere

Comment: A simple and straightforward approach is to construct truth tables if you have a few primitive statements or logical variables.

Answer (score 2):

Claim:
$$
(p \rightarrow q) \lor (q \land r) \equiv \neg ((p \land \neg r) \land \neg q) \land \neg (r \land (\neg q \land p))
$$
LHS:
$$
(p \rightarrow q) \lor (q \land r) \equiv (\neg p \lor q) \lor (q \land r) \equiv ((\neg p  \lor q) \lor q ) \land ((\neg p \lor q) \lor r) \equiv \\ (\neg p  \lor q ) \land ((\neg p \lor q) \lor r) \equiv (\neg p \lor q) 
$$
RHS:
$$
\neg ((p \land \neg r) \land \neg q) \land \neg (r \land (\neg q \land p)) \equiv \\
\neg [((p \land \neg r) \land \neg q) \lor (r \land (\neg q \land p))] \equiv \\
\neg [((\neg q \land p) \land \neg r) \lor ((\neg q \land p) \land r)] \equiv \\
\neg [((\neg q \land p)  \land (r \lor \neg r)] \equiv \\
q \lor \neg p \equiv (\neg p \lor q) 
$$

so LHS = RHS and the Claim is true.

Comment: How do you justify the first step for the RHS?

Comment: $\neg (p' \lor q') \equiv \neg p' \land \neg q'$

Comment: Then shouldn't the second line for the RHS read: $\neg [\neg((p \land \neg r) \land \neg q) \lor (r \land (\neg q \land p))]$?

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId  ??????? if you do that you will negate the negation of $\neg [\neg((p \land \neg r) \land \neg q) \lor ]$ getting $((p \land \neg r) \land \neg q) $ at the beginning which is clearly not $\neg((p \land \neg r) \land \neg q)$ as the original RHS states

Comment: Oh my mistake, I misread your parenthesis. This is fine.

Comment: You can consider upvoting, since you realize this is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Convert each side to DNF (an OR of ANDs) using the identities:

> - $x \to y \equiv \neg x \lor y$
> - $\neg (x \lor y) \equiv \neg x \land \neg y$
> - $\neg (x_1 \land \cdots \land x_n) \equiv \neg x_1 \lor \cdots \lor \neg x_n$

Comment: This isn't an answer, this is a hint. It's a good hint, but still just a hint.

Comment: @chharvey And the OP asked for "Any suggestions or tips", and a hint is a tip is a hint in my book. :-)

Comment: fair enough : )

Answer (score 0):

First let’s recall a few laws.

- definition of implication: $a\implies b \equiv \lnot a \lor b$
- DeMorgan's Laws:

  - $a \lor b \equiv \lnot(\lnot a \land \lnot b)$
  - $a \land b \equiv \lnot(\lnot a \lor \lnot b)$
- Commutation:

  - $a \lor b \equiv b \lor a$
  - $a \land b \equiv b \land a$
- Association:

  - $(a \lor b) \lor c \equiv a \lor (b \lor c)$
  - $(a \land b) \land c \equiv a \land (b \land c)$
- Distribution:

  - $a \lor (b \land c) \equiv (a \lor b) \land (a \lor c)$
  - $a \land (b \lor c) \equiv (a \land b) \lor (a \land c)$
- Idempotency:

  - $a \lor a \equiv a$
  - $a \land a \equiv a$
- Identity:

  - $a \lor \bot \equiv a$
  - $a \land \top \equiv a$
- Zero:

  - $a \lor \top \equiv \top$
  - $a \land \bot \equiv \bot$

Starting with the RHS and working backward,
\begin{align}
\lnot((p \land \lnot r) \land \lnot q) &\land \lnot(r \land (\lnot q \land p))\\
\lnot(p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r) &\land \lnot(p \land \lnot q \land r) \quad\text{Association and Commutation}\\
(\lnot p \lor q \lor r) &\land (\lnot p \lor q \lor \lnot r) \quad\text{DeMorgan}\\
((p \implies q) \lor r) &\land ((p \implies q) \lor \lnot r) \quad\text{dfn. of impl.}\\
(p \implies q) &\lor (r \land \lnot r) \quad\text{Distribution}\\
(p \implies q) &\lor \bot \quad\text{dfn. of Contradiction}\\
p &\implies q \quad\text{Identity}\\
\end{align}

Now starting with the LHS and working forward,
\begin{align}
(p \implies q) &\lor (q \land r)\\
((p \implies q) \lor q) &\land ((p \implies q) \lor r) \quad\text{Distribution}\\
((\lnot p \lor q) \lor q) &\land ((p \implies q) \lor r) \quad\text{dfn. of impl.}\\
(\lnot p \lor q) &\land ((p \implies q) \lor r) \quad\text{Associativity and Idempotency}\\
(p \implies q) &\land ((p \implies q) \lor r) \quad\text{dfn. of impl.}\\
((p \implies q) \lor \bot) &\land ((p \implies q) \lor r) \quad\text{Identity}\\
(p \implies q) &\lor (\bot \land r) \quad\text{Distribution}\\
(p \implies q) &\lor \bot \quad\text{Zero}\\
p &\implies q \quad\text{Identity}\\
\end{align}

Therefore both the LHS and RHS are logically equivalent to $p \implies q$, and by Transitivity of equivalence, the LHS and the RHS are logically equivalent to each other.

Comment: You didn't make a mistake - I did (d'oh!). The RHS is supposed to be ¬((p∧¬r)∧¬q), not ¬((p∧r)∧¬q). I've updated the equation. Thanks for your help. PS: The "squares" law is called idempotency. Just in case you were still wondering.

Comment: why only editing your answer instead of upvoting the one that already provided the solution? Besides most of what you did is based on that solution.

Comment: It's called "Absorption Law" btw....  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsorptionLaw.html

Comment: I find it odd, that you copy my answer (modified it a bit) and submit it as yours....

Comment: @Anonymous as hard as it may be to realize that there are other people with intelligence in this world, I arrived at my solution independently from yours. I can send you screenshots of my hand-written scratch work if you'd like.

Comment: Then why commenting "not sure of this step...." ? in one of your edits? Besides in your very first answer you were only defining stuff not dealing with the problem is after my answer that you "started" (copied) the process

Comment: @Anonymous because, as I'm sure you know, the first answer is not always perfect. it takes many revisions to get it right. I'll admit I took that one step from your answer, which at the time I wasn't sure of, but the important part is that I went back and proved it later on when I had time. I never take material I don't understand and claim it as my own. but if mathematicians weren't allowed to borrow material from one another, we'd still be in the Stone Age. get off your high horse and stop fretting over reputation points.